# AesManaged - Padding is Invalid and Cannot Be Removed - Reading from .Txt File

Tags: encryption

I am trying to save encrypted data to a Text file and then open and decrypt it.  When I try to Decrypt it I receive the error "Padding is Invalid and Cannot Be Removed."  I am using example code directly from Microsoft for encryption and decryption.

Here is MY code to encrypt and save file:

```
                    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(credentials);
                    using (AesManaged myAes = new AesManaged())
                    {

                        byte[] encrypted = ControlHelperscs.EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(json, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
                        File.WriteAllBytes(subPath, encrypted);
                    }
```

Here is my code to Retrieve and Decrypt file:

```
                using (AesManaged myAes = new AesManaged())
            {

                    byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(subPath);

                    string decrypt = ControlHelperscs.DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(file, myAes.Key, myAes.IV);
                    credentials = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginModel>(decrypt);

            }
```

Here are Encrypt and Decrypt methods:

```
        public static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
        byte[] encrypted;

        // Create an AesManaged object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for encryption.
            using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        //Write all data to the stream.
                        swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                    }
                    encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }


        // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
        return encrypted;

    }

    public static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
        if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");

        // Declare the string used to hold
        // the decrypted text.
        string plaintext = null;

        // Create an AesManaged object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
        {
            aesAlg.Key = Key;
            aesAlg.IV = IV;

            // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

            // Create the streams used for decryption.
            using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            {
                using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                    {

                        // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                        // and place them in a string.
                        plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        return plaintext;

    }
```

Comment: It also looks liked you're using a fixed IV - this largely defeats the point of CBC mode.  It is insecure.

Comment: Actually, I got that code from Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aes?view=netframework-4.8.  That is why I don't understand why it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @Jesse C. Slicer (received error: "FlushFinalBlock() method was called twice on a CryptoStream. It can only be called once."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry I deleted my comment (it was wrong in that context), but I reworked your example to have a little less boilerplate and be able to encrypt and decrypt properly. The problem is that you're generating a new and different Key/IV pair to decrypt from the one you used to encrypt. Of course it won't be able to decrypt. So, here is the part to make it work:

```
        byte[] key;
        byte[] iv;

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(credentials);
        using (AesManaged myAes = new AesManaged())
        {
            key = myAes.Key;
            iv = myAes.IV;
            byte[] encrypted = ControlHelperscs.EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(json, key, iv);
            File.WriteAllBytes(subPath, encrypted);
        }

        byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(subPath);

        string decrypt = ControlHelperscs.DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(file, key, iv);
        credentials = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginModel>(decrypt);
```

and here are the slightly reworked heavy-lifting methods to be a bit more compact:

```
    public static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (plainText is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(plainText));
        }

        if (plainText.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(plainText), plainText, "length cannot be zero");
        }

        if (key is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
        }

        if (key.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(key), key, "length cannot be zero");
        }

        if (iv is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(iv));
        }

        if (iv.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(iv), iv, "length cannot be zero");
        }

        // Create an AesManaged object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
        // Create the streams used for encryption.
        using (SymmetricAlgorithm aesAlg = new AesManaged { Key = key, IV = iv })
        using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV))
        using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
        using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        using (TextWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
        {
            // Write all data to the stream.
            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
            swEncrypt.Flush();
            csEncrypt.FlushFinalBlock();

            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
            return msEncrypt.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        // Check arguments.
        if (cipherText is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cipherText));
        }

        if (cipherText.Length ==  0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(cipherText), cipherText, "length cannot be zero");
        }

        if (key is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));
        }

        if (key.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(key), key, "length cannot be zero");
        }

        if (iv is null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(iv));
        }

        if (iv.Length == 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(iv), iv, "length cannot be zero");
        }

        // Create an AesManaged object
        // with the specified key and IV.
        // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
        // Create the streams used for decryption.
        using (SymmetricAlgorithm aesAlg = new AesManaged { Key = key, IV = iv })
        using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV))
        using (Stream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
        using (Stream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        using (TextReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
        {
            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
            // and place them in a string.
            return srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your assistance, the problem here is that the user will never open the saved text file in the same method in which it is saved, so there is no way to use the same keys.  I would need a way to know what the key is at time of decryption.  So they keys would then have to be saved to the file system.  I will try saving keys to text file and opening and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I truly appreciate your help.